How can I add button to a Slack message that initiates a slash command as that user?
I have an existing slash command that I would like to create a button to launch as the user who clicked the button. The slash command uses a webhook to pull up a form for the user to fill out. I would like to make a button that does the same thing. The button will likely be sent to the user in the channel as a whisper as to not fill up the channel. I'm pretty sure I can use a workflow for that part.
Alternatively if a workflow can launch the webhook that too would be acceptable.
I have started designing the message with the blockkit tool but not sure what data I put in the action to launch the slash command or webhook.
I have tried using url in  blockkit and found it tried to open the webhook. This resulted in 404.
